# c# generics. Trying to set columns generically for a grid control

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, generics

I need some help on how to set the list of columns for a a grid control generically. I have a 3rd party library with the following method signature I want to use:

```
 public GridControl SetColumns<T>(Action<GridColumnModelList<T>> initCols)
```

In my Controller on the action method I get a generic model the contains the list of columns I want displaying:

```
 var gridprofile = new GridProfile<SiteVisitSearchGridViewModel>(gridProfileid);
```

I now want to create the grid control and apply my columns to it but dont know how to do this:

```
GridControl gc = new GridControl();
gc.SetColumns<SiteVisitSearchGridViewModel>(gridprofile.Columns);
```

help please

thanks
Andy

Comment: that's an awkward API there - the SetColumns method requires an Action delegate - not a collection of columns. You have to call it something like this gc.SetColumns<SiteVisitSearchGridViewModel>(columns => do something with gridprofile.Columns here);

Comment: Thanks for the help, it does seem awkward to me but I have no experience of Action delegates. It is the lambda expression bit I am having the issue with. :(

Answer (score 1):

you could try something(it may not compile - I don't have that library installed) like this:

```
gc.SetColumns<SiteVisitSearchGridViewModel>(columns => 
{
    foreach(col in gridprofile.Columns)
        columns.Add(x => new GridColumnModel(col.Name));
});
```